# move/copy workspace

Tags: catkin

[image: Rosanswers logo]

is there a tool to copy or move a workspace that would minimize rebuilding time?

example: I have lots of repos in my workspace, rebuilding from scratch takes 15 minutes. Plus there is a lot of test data that takes a long time to download.

I would like to be working on multiple issues at the same time, i.e. I work on issue 1 and while somebody else is reviewing my pull request I would like to work on issue 2, etc. I want to be able to switch back and forth quickly between those 2 code bases.

Working with branches and switching between them is the simple solution, but it has drawbacks as well: while I am in the middle of making my changes, I have a lot on uncommited changes, I need to stash them, switch branch, rebuild, etc...

working with multiple workspaces is great, but then to initially create the workspace is a drag because of the build and download time

So I'd like to be able to copy workspace for issue 1 as a new workspace for issue 2. This way, after I switch branches and make some code modifications, it recompiles quickly.

I tried a simple workspace copy and edited the CMakeCache to switch the workspace root folder, but then when I compiled it basically recompiled from scratch...

I'm sure I am not the first one to think about this, so I was hoping that there might be a tool just for that...

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/205326/move/copy-workspace/) by [brice rebsamen](https://answers.ros.org/users/597/brice-rebsamen/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1001 on 2015-03-18

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [William](https://answers.ros.org/users/10/william/) on 2015-03-18**:
What tool are you using to build with?

**Comment by [brice rebsamen](https://answers.ros.org/users/597/brice-rebsamen/) on 2015-03-18**:
catkin_make

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

EDIT: To answer your question directly, no I don't think there are any tools like that.

---

Can you just:

- Create a new workspace
- Clone/copy and change branches for the packages you are changing and
- Symlink from the other workspace any packages which depend on it?
- Then in a new terminal source the first workspace and build the second one you just constructed?

This way you only have to build the package your changing and its dependents, which you have to rebuild anyways. At least you don't have to rebuild the packages which the package you are changing depends on.

Also, if you're not using `ccache` (https://ccache.samba.org/), you should, that will help on repeat compiles.

---

Originally posted by [William](https://answers.ros.org/users/10/william/) with karma: 17335 on 2015-03-18

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2015-03-19**:
+1 on `ccache`. I use it all the time. And the combination `ccache` and `distcc` makes things even faster.